# How to recreate this background fade in/pop-up effect icon button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to recreate these buttons(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GF6E7VPsBSA/XMMOk4a69nI/AAAAAAAABIw/CYqpVYpB3eAeO-afm8lso414SEczglCvgCK8BGAs/s0/2019-04-26.png) on https://www.jobhop.vn/vi but I cant seem to get it right.

I tried using the hover property in css.

This is my code:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #B17461;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#B17461, #B17461);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  transition: background-size .5s, color .5s;
}
div:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Right-click the icon and inspect it. Look at the `.blind` element, in both default and hover states. It's all right there.

Comment: It's confusing, can you provide me with some sample code?

Comment: No. I'm not going to code it for you. Simply right-click one of the icons and inspect the `.blind` element. The browser will show you the styles for that element. Dev Tools will also allow you to toggle the states of elements, like hover. Learning how to use tools available to you will make you a better developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the blue circle already exists underneath the icon, it's just zoomed out/hidden. On hover you animate the circle and change the icon color to white:

```
ul li .icon svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    color: #4f4f4f;
}
ul li .blind {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #173b66;
  opacity: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
ul li:hover .icon svg {
  color: #fff;
}
ul li:hover .blind {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j245rxwk/

Btw: most of this CSS is directly from your linked website

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for, and thanks for the explanation too.

Comment: I have a question, what is these lines `data-v-b12e8260`?

Comment: You can ignore/remove those, it's from JobHop's HTML. They use a framework (VueJS) that adds those for scoped styling https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html but they're not needed here

Comment: Ok. Thanks again!